# Google App Engine - Always running instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want my App Engine to always have one instance running. I want to avoid that the first request after 15 minutes of no traffc takes like 20 seconds to finish. There is a feature called "Always on" that is mentioned several places to fix this, but I can't find it anywhere on App Engine.

I've tried to set min-idle-instances to 1 but it still starts a new instance after 15 minutes of no traffic. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Always-on" is deprecated (I believe it does not exist any more). The configurations that currently let you do that, and more, are documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/ ; for example if you always want one instance running, neither more nor less, set the default module of your app to manual scaling, with `instances` set to `1`.

However, automatic scaling with `min-idle-instances` should also work *if* you have followed the instructions (at the URL I just gave)

> For resident instances to function properly, you must be sure that warmup requests are enabled and your application handles warmup requests.

Use, again as that URL recommends, "The Availability column of the Developers Console Instance page" to check which of your instances are actually `resident` (as you wish) rather than `dynamic` (i.e, going away after some idle time).

Comment: Thanks, I do have warmup enabled, and the resident instance has been running since I set the min-idle-instances. But when doing a new request now, it still sometimes creates a new dynamic instance anyway.

Comment: @André, if you want full control of instance creation (in particular, no auto creation of new instances when our autoscaler predicts they'll be needed in the near future), then manual scaling is the way to go, as I mentioned. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService (specifically `setNumInstances`) to dynamically control the number of instances for your module.

Comment: I have found `min-idle-instances` does not work in what the OP is asking. On the warm-up docs it says "if your app is serving no traffic, the first request to the app will always be a loading request, not a warmup request." - that loading request will take time, even if you have warm-up requests configured... so you still get initial latency if no one has hit your API in a while.

Comment: The URL changed - the needed reference details can be seen at:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements_automatic_scaling

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use AppEngine Managed VM. The application interface is compatible, but you get a VM that's always on. For more information see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms.